# Can't prevent multiple click/touch on button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button

I have 26 images (GameObjects) where each image has a button.
If a button is clicked, it plays a sound and animation.

However, I have a problem. I have tried to prevent this, but if I perform a **multi touch / stress test**, some buttons cannot be clicked anymore. If I click slowly it works fine, but if I perform multiple clicks on a button then it will fail/can't be clicked anymore. Any idea why?

My source code :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using DG.Tweening;

[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]
public class z_abcLetter_Main : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject InputData;
    public List<GameObject> List_uGUI;

    private List<Sprite> List_Sprite;
    private List<AudioClip> List_AudioClip;

    private int currentIndex;
    private GameObject currentGameObject;
    private GameObject parentGameObject;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        List_Sprite = InputData.GetComponent<z_abcLetter_InputData>().Daftar_element;
        List_AudioClip = InputData.GetComponent<z_abcLetter_InputData>().Daftar_Suara;

        int total_element = List_Sprite.Count;


        for (int i = 0; i < total_element; i++)
        {
            List_uGUI[i].GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Image>().sprite = List_Sprite[i];
            List_uGUI[i].GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Image>().preserveAspect = true;
        }
    }

    public void onButtonClick()
    {

        currentIndex =  int.Parse(EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.transform.parent.name.ToString());
        currentGameObject = EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject;
        parentGameObject = currentGameObject.transform.parent.gameObject;
        StartCoroutine(PlaySoundWithAnimation());

    }

    IEnumerator PlaySoundWithAnimation()
    {
        currentGameObject.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Button>().enabled = false;
        currentGameObject.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Button>().interactable = false;

        AudioSource audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        audio.clip = List_AudioClip[currentIndex];
        audio.Play();
        parentGameObject.transform.DOPunchScale(new Vector3(2, 2, 0), 1, 1, 1);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f);

        currentGameObject.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Button>().enabled = true;
        currentGameObject.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Button>().interactable = true;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Comment: you need edit your question and rephrase some stuff. You said *"Cant prevent multiple click"* then in the body *"but if I perform a multi touch / stress test, some buttons cannot be clicked anymore"*. It seems like you're trying to prevent multi-touch but then it looks like you're complaining that multi-touch is not working...It would be easier to explain your problem, what you expect to happen instead.

Comment: my expectation : "after random stress test / multiple click fastly to one button, my button can be clicked again". but now it can't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to behave as expected. But for fast multiple clicks, you need to reset your coroutine.

To do that, you need a reference to PlaySoundWithAnimation.

```
private IEnumerator coroutine;

void Start()
{
    coroutine = PlaySoundWithAnimation();
}

public void onButtonClick()
{
    StopCoroutine(coroutine);
    // you also need to stop audio here
    //...
    StartCoroutine(coroutine);
}
```

see: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html

The reason some buttons are not responding is because the coroutines are stacked and they're all waiting for `yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f);`

see: https://answers.unity.com/questions/309613/calling-startcoroutine-multiple-times-seems-to-sta.html

**Note:**
If you don't want to stop the clip, consider `audio.clip.length` before enabling the buttons.